# error during importing module in openerp for windos xp version?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I am using this code in openerp7 for directoly print from printer this code I was written in main.py, but when I start server it gives unhandled error on my browser console actually this error happen with importing win32print module.

```
import win32print
printer=OpenPrinter(win32print.GetDefaultPrinter())
hJob = win32print.StartDocPrinter (printer, 1, ("RVGI Print", None, "RAW"))
g=open('test3.txt','r')
raw_data = bytes ( open( 'test3.txt' , 'r').read ())
try:
    win32print.StartPagePrinter (printer)
    win32print.WritePrinter (printer, raw_data)
    win32print.EndPagePrinter (printer)
finally:
    win32print.EndDocPrinter (printer)
    win32print.ClosePrinter (printer)
```

Comment: *What error* are you getting? Please include the full traceback if you have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your code, I can find only problem that is `undefined variable OpenPrinter` which can be rectified by merely replacing OpenPrinter() with `win32print.OpenPrinter()`